# Migrated questions aren't updated live

Tags: bug, status-completed, migrated-questions, live-refresh

If a question arrives at a site's front page via migration, it doesn't show up on the front page if you're relying on the new live updates.

That is, its arrival isn't announced to listening clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good catch - migrated questions will be shown in the live updates after the next build.