# Questions bumped by Community aren't updated live

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-user, bump, live-refresh

Well, you know the drill, [same deal as before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126668/migrated-questions-arent-updated-live).

If a question is bumped by [Community](/users/-1/community), it doesn't appear as a question with new activity for people who are using the new realtime thingadongdong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Community bumps will be part of the realtime feature as well.  Look for this in the next deploy.