# Do migrated questions get bumped to the front page?

Tags: support, migration, bump

When a question gets migrated, does it get bumped to the front page of the target site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If a question is migrated, its last activity date on the target site is set to the time of the migration, and thus it appears on the front page.

This even [works with the realtime updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126668/migrated-questions-arent-updated-live/126880#126880).

Comment: I hoped so. But after following a few migrated questions that didn't receive **any** attention on the target site, doubt entered my mind...

Comment: @Dennis, I recently noticed the same and was coming here to ask about it. I've noticed that on SO in particular many don't get much attention but it seems to mostly be if they aren't re-tagged and end up left with obscure tags.